# CTE optimisations

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I recently noticed a poor performing query that contained a CTE.

From running `EXPLAIN` it appears that if I have 2 consecutive tables in a CTE, the first of which has a `WHERE` filter applied the postgres optimizer doesn't actually restrict the row set down, and so the second table lookup is very slow:

```
WITH thing_data AS (
    SELECT * FROM things WHERE id = '0000000001'
), thing_readings AS (
    SELECT  thing_timestamp
    FROM reading_log_instantaneous_schedule
    INNER JOIN thing_data
    ON thing_id = thing_data.id
    ORDER BY thing_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
),                   
SELECT thing_data.*
FROM thing_data
LEFT OUTER JOIN thing_readings
ON thing_data.id = thing_readings.thing_id
```

Basically the inner join in the readings table is not benefiting from the `INNER JOIN thing_data on thing_id = thing_data.id`, and is actually doing a scan across all the rows in the reading table.

Is it possible to kick the optimizer to notice that I have limited down the `thing_data` record set to just one row, therefore making the subsequent join quick, instead of super slow?

Edit: Apologies for a poorly anonymised query.

I have created a SQLFiddle demonstrating the problem I am having - I still have to add 2 `WHERE` clauses (bad for code maintainability etc)  - the problem persists even when forgetting about CTEs and using a regular join table as Craig suggested. I am more used to SQL Server which did not have this issue when I converted the schema.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/17c82/1

Comment: What if you use WHERE id = '0000000001' in the filter for reading_log_instantaneous_schedule also?

Comment: My example is simplified and what you suggested isnt always possible for my use case.

Comment: It is even _over_ simplified: the thing_readings CTE does not have the thing_id in the select list.

Comment: You don't use `reading` despite `SELECT`ing it in the subquery. As written I think your "simplified" query is still just an incredibly roundabout way to do an `EXISTS` test. Is `readings.reading` supposed to be included in the final select list or tested in the outer where clause? Badly anonymized queries are a waste of everyone's time, -1 . **Explain the purpose of the query** please.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to kick the optimizer to notice that I have limited down the thing_data record set to just one row, therefore making the subsequent join quick, instead of super slow?

Not in PostgreSQL, at least in 9.4 or older. Hopefully it'll change later.

CTEs in PostgreSQL are *optimisation fences* - essentially, the planner can't push qualifiers down into them, or pull qualifiers up out of them.

When this is a problem, you need to go back to using a subquery in the `FROM` clause, old-style.

```
SELECT thing_data.*
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM things WHERE id = '0000000001'
) data_thing
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT  thing_timestamp 
    FROM reading_log_instantaneous_schedule 
    INNER JOIN thing_data on thing_id = thing_data.id 
    ORDER BY thing_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)
thing_readings 
ON thing_data.id = thing_readings.thing_id;
```

since a subquery in `FROM` *does* permit qualifier push-down / pull-up. In this case, though, you really want to apply the `WHERE` clause laterally. This is best done by further simplifying, getting rid of the subquery:

```
SELECT thing_data.*
FROM things
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT  thing_timestamp 
    FROM reading_log_instantaneous_schedule 
    INNER JOIN thing_data on thing_id = thing_data.id 
    ORDER BY thing_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)
thing_readings 
ON thing_data.id = thing_readings.thing_id
WHERE things.id = '0000000001'
```

However, the whole thing appears to be a hugely overcomplicated way of just doing this (based on your SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/17c82/3):

```
SELECT  things.*, thingreadings.reading 
FROM things 
LEFT OUTER JOIN thingreadings ON thingreadings.thingid = things.id
WHERE things.id = '1'
ORDER BY reading DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I just tried this approach and the same problem persists - the EXPLAIN still shows a massive performance hit. Obviously if I hard code the WHERE clause a second time into the outer join then the plan costs nearly nothing, but I am trying to avoid doing that.

Comment: @GrahamB Yeah, the issue is that the `WHERE` clause wouldn't be pushed down, it'd be lateral, and Pg won't do that. Take a look at the updated approach.  The `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` may be horrible for performance too.

Comment: @GrahamB Also, in anonymizing your query, you've made it nonsensical.  `thing_readings.thing_id` isn't in the select-list for the subquery, and `thing_timestamp` isn't used. I suspect you can do away with all these subqueries and the `LIMIT` entirely, but with a bogus non-working query I can't really tell. Please post a *working* query, along with create table and insert statements to provide dummy data for it to work on.

Comment: @CraigRinger: yes, that what I said in a comment to the OP one hour ago.

Comment: See my edit for an example of the problem I am having with this approach too.

Comment: @GrahamB Answer edited. I think you need to explain what you want, properly, with both words and a correct query test case that demonstrates the complexities and different cases your actual query tries to handle. Otherwise this is just a waste of time.